# PreRemoveFromViewEvent is not triggered

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hello,

I have a requirement, to perform some functionality before the user navigates away from current page (navigation may be either by forward or redirect).

So I thought I'd use this system event called `PreRemoveFromViewEvent` on any one of the components on the page.

`PreRemoveFromViewEvent` has always been a theoretical concept to me, I never used it practically.

So I applied this event on `h:inputText` and thought that it will fire the event when user navigates away from page and this `h:inputText` will be removed from view before loading the new page/view.

But this is not firing.

Am I using it right?
Am I using it on right component?
Will it serve the purpose of firing event before navigating away?

Here is my code:

```
<h:inputText id="abc">
    <f:event listener="#{myManagedBean.preRemoveFromViewHandler}"     
             type="javax.faces.event.PreRemoveFromViewEvent"/> 
</h:inputText>

<p:commandButton action="page2.xhtml" value="NEXT"/>
```

Listener:

```
public void preRemoveFromViewHandler(PreRemoveFromViewEvent prfve){
      //USER is navigating away so save the data
}
```

*USING: JSF Mojarra 2.1.13 | Primefaces: 3.5*

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `PreDestroyViewMapEvent` instead, registered within the `<h:body/>` or `<f:view/>`. This event is the one that's fired when one is navigating away from a view. From the specification:

> Immediately before the Map is destroyed, a PreDestroyViewMapEvent must be published using UIViewRoot as the event source

The `PreRemoveFromViewEvent` is fired only when the parent component is removed from the viewmap, something that doesn't necessarily happen when a the navigating away from the page.

Comment: Hi kolossus, this event is also not firing. May be I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @KishorP - you might need to post more of your xhtml here